# read string from Qt application by reverse engineering

Tags: qt, qml, reverse-engineering

I want to programmatically read a string generated in runtime by a basic Qt GUI application.

The string appears on the screen but I don't have the source and I want to pass this string to another script.

Here's the relevant .qml file:

```
import QtQuick 1.0 

Rectangle { 
id: tagCloud 

SystemPalette { id: palette }   //we get the system default colors from this 

//public API 
property variant model 
property color baseColor: palette.base 
property color textColor: palette.text 
property int   textFontSize: 16 

color: baseColor 

Flow { 
    id: flow 
    width: parent.width 
    spacing: 15 
    anchors.margins: 4 
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter 

    //property int maxHeight:0 

    Repeater { 
        id: repeater 
        model: tagCloud.model 

        Text { 
            id: textBlock 
            text: category 
            font.pointSize: tagCloud.textFontSize; 
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

Is there an easy way to get the "category" string as it's being generated?

Edit: This is the link to the application,
http://cybertron.cg.tu-berlin.de/eitz/projects/classifysketch/sketchpad_win.zip

Comment: Add an array as property to flow, oncomponentcomplete on the Text, add category to array?

Comment: Do you have possibility to modify the source code of QML files? P.S. It seems, that in theory you can modify just QML file (even if it's embedded into the binary as resource) and add code to write this string into the file on the disk, for example.

Comment: I tried changing the font size (textFontSize) but it didn't have any visible effect, so I think that the qml files are already loaded into the binary. arrynaq, how do you suggest to do this?

Comment: Max Go, can you elaborate?

Comment: Added a link to the Qt application.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I was wrong, the qml files affect the binary after all. I tried changing the spacing variable and it had visible changes.

Comment: Edit2: Tried arynaq's advice but it results in a blank GUI showing up.

Comment: So what I need is a way to write to a file with QML (Qt4) only (without any C++) and without using additional imports other than QtQuick 1.0 and CustomComponents 1.0 . Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "passing to another script"? To another QML file, a JavaScript function in a file loaded by the QML engine, an external program?

Comment: An external Python program.

Comment: Is this possible?